# Can NHibernate map column to a table?

Tags: c#, mysql, xml, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am creating mapping xml files for a database, but I have an object `LogObj` which I would like to map to different tables (with the same schema) depending upon which `logid` is passed.

For example, the table `tblsystemlogs` contains a column `logstable` which can contain various table names such as `tbllogsprod`, `tbllogstest`, `tbllogsdev`.

The query is: `SELECT logstable FROM tblsystemlogs WHERE logid = {0};`

Comment: what's the question? what have you tried?

Comment: @MartinErnst The question is can it be done. I am not sure if I could create a view inside the xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with [Table Per Concrete Class](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance-tableperconcrete) mapping.

You would have some kind of base abstract class - ie. Log, and three concrete implementations LogProduction, LogTest and LogDev.

SystemLog class would then have a property Log with [any mapping](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-types-anymapping), and logstable column would serve as a meta column.

Comment: This definitely looks like what I was looking for. I will give it a try once I have the remaining 20 tables mapped.